# How to count numbers and characters of a string?

Tags: c

I have to do this excercise and I'm really trying to do my best, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

It says I need to code a program to analyze a string. And it needs to give the numbers of words and numbers.

Note that a number is also a word.
123 is a word and a number, but for example 4HIMATE is not a number, only a word.

I'll let my code of what I got so far

```
int main()

{
int size= 256;

char s[256]= "Hi 123 Peter 8hi hi8";
char space[]= " ";


int wordCount= 0;
int numberCount= 0;

strcat(s, space);

strlwr(s);

for(int i= 0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    if(s[i+1]== ' ' && s[i]>96 && s[i]<123)
    {
        wordCount++;
    }

    if(s[i+1]== ' ' && s[i]>47 && s[i]<58)
    {
        wordCount++;
    }

}

for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
{

    if(s[j+1]== ' ' && s[j]>47 && s[j]<58)
    {
        numberCount++;
    }
}

printf("Words= %d\n", wordCount);
printf("Numbers= %d", numberCount);

return 0;
}
```

My output needs to be=

Words= 5
Numbers= 1

But the mistake is on numbers, the output is 2.

I don't really know how to solve that, so I need some help.

Corrected some mistakes (edit):

```
 for(int i= 0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
    if(s[i+1]== ' ' && s[i]>'a' && s[i]<'z')
    {
        wordCount++;
    }

    if(s[i+1]== ' ' && s[i]>'0' && s[i]<'9')
    {
        wordCount++;
    }

}

for (int j=0; s[j]!='\0'; j++)
{

    if(s[j+1]== ' ' && s[j]>'0' && s[j]<'9')
    {
        numberCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean using something like [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen)?

Comment: Also, your first loop uses the fact that `s` is a null-terminated byte string, but you don't do that in the second loop. In your second loop you use the whole array, even the parts of the array that are not initialized and which contain *indeterminate* values (that could be seen as somewhat random or garbage).

Comment: And don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). It seems you should learn about [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification). And probably read a few decent books which should tell you all about these functions.

Comment: You´re right, I didn´t realized the mistake on the second loop. I'm kinda new on this language, sorry.

Comment: But the main problem here is that I don't get the correct result, and I just used the ASCII codes (magic numbers) of the characters, I don't know if that's wrong. I changed them, you can have a look of the edited code on the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed, as you won't be counting the last "word" (`hi8`) as a word. Similarly you won't count "numbers" if they are last in the string. This could be found out through some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

One possible solution is to use *states*. One state that tells if you are in a word or not, and another state that tells if the current word is all digits or not.

Using states, when looping over the string you check if the current character [is an alpha-numeric character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalnum). If it is, and the is-a-word state is not set then set that state. When changing the state, then also check if the current character [is a digit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) and if it is then set the is-number state. Continuing the loop, if is-a-word state is set, and the current character is *not* a digit, then you clear the is-number state. When reaching something that [is a space](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) then you check your states: If is-a-word is set, then clear it and increase the word counter; If is-number state is set, then increase the number counter and clear the state.

In *pseudo* code it could be something like this:

```
is-a-word-state = false
is-a-number-state = false

for each character in string
{
    if (current-character is alphanumeric and is-a-word-state == false)
    {
        // Started a new word
        is-a-word-state = true

        if (current-character is digit)
        {
            // Could be a number
            is-a-number-state = true
        }
    }

    if (current-character is not digit)
    {
        // Current word (if any) is not a number
        is-a-number-state = false
    }

    if (current-character is space)
    {
        if (is-a-word-state == true)
        {
            // End of the current word
            word-counter++

            if (is-a-number-state == true)
            {
                // Word is a number
                number-counter++
            }
        }

        is-a-word-state = false
        is-a-number-state = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it's more clear for me. I never learned pseudo code, but I understand the meaning of it. I'll try to do it again with your advice.

Comment: @Cid Pseudo code means just that: it is not real code in any language, but posted just so you understand the algorithm part. So there's no formal language called "pseudo code" or such :)